# Optimal vs Optimum

Tags: soft-question, optimization

What is the difference when a mathematician says, in respect to some optimization, "optimal" point vs "optimum" point?

Can we use them as nouns too? I mean like "The optimal is..." or "The optimum is...".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Optimal" is an adjective, "optimum" a noun.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I see optimum used as an adjective too, like "optimum solution" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: Well, what can I say - let me quote the great philosopher: verbing weirds language. In other words, people abuse language all the time. Some abuses become accepted.

Comment: @DanielFischer :) thanks

Comment: @Daniel: H/T for the Calvin and Hobbes reference!

Comment: *Optimum* as an adjective goes back at least to $1885$, which is less than $40$ years after the earliest OED citation for it as a noun.

Comment: Interesting, @Brian. Learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: As my brother would say, "the use of good English is went".